# Appending text based on condition

Tags: excel

Is it possible to sort the table from the left hand side into the table on the right hand side? Does it need any query execution or just sort will do? Is it even possible to make each cell contains more than one value?

[image: Table in excel]

Comment: If you do not have TEXTJOIN() it will require vba.

Comment: Your picture looks like google sheets.  with that you can use Join() and Filter() to return the correct answer.

Comment: @pnuts, I took the liberty to adjust the title to something less cringeworthy.

Comment: Sadly, I'm using Excel 2010 so it doesn't equip with TEXTJOIN().... Is it difficult to write the code in vba?

Comment: Search the internet for code that is better than Concatenate(). You will find many approaches. I don't know if the many UDFs out there will be able to use the nested IF with the array argument, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2016 (with an Office 365 subscription), you can use the new TextJoin function in combination with a condition. This required that the formula is confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, because it is now an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$20=$D4,$A$2:$A$20,""))
```

[image]